# Ubuntu touch app store questions

Tags: ubuntu, app-store, qml, ubuntu-touch

I have uploaded my apps in the Ubuntu touch app store.I have uploaded the ARM version of it.If I want it to be available on amd64 or i386 do I also have to upload the other 2 versions?(I know stupid question,but I feel nervous about it,I don't want to get banned from the store)

Also when unity 8 becomes the default for desktop Ubuntu,will users be able to download my apps on their desktop pc's?

The apps were made with qml and the Ubuntu sdk.Though they need a lot more testing.They were packaged as click packages.

Comment: You should create **multi** arch package. see how to do it [here](http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2014/12/creating-mutli-arch-click-packages.html)

Comment: Thanky you but it was resolved a long time ago.